# Elegant way to code search within a nested json with arrays inside it in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Json to be searched:

```
{ "results": 
  { "key1": 
    [ { "step": "step1", "result": "pass"    } 
    , { "step": "step2", "result": "pending" } 
    ] 
  } 
, "key2": 
  [ { "step": "step3", "result": "pass"    } 
  , { "step": "step4", "result": "pending" } 
  ] 
}
```

When given a key as Input, It should return for that key,
`status=pass` if all steps have `result=pass`.
`If` any of the result are fail, `return fail`.
`Else if` any of the status are pending, `return pending`.

Is there an elegant yet understandable way to code this ?

Here is my working version.

```
let subState              = "key1";
let validationResultsJson = validationReportJson["results"];
let validationKeys        = Object.keys(validationResultsJson);
if (validationKeys.includes(subState)) {
    let subStateArr = Object.values(validationResultsJson[subState]);
    let result      = '';
    for (let eachStep of subStateArr) {
        result += eachStep.result;
    }
    if (result.indexOf("fail") > -1) {
        console.log("fail");
    } else if (result.indexOf("pending") > -1) {
        console.log("pending");
    } else {
        console.log("pass");
    }
} else {
    console.error("subState doesn't exist");
}
```

TIA

Comment: Your data is not valid JavaScript. Either `key1` and `key2` should be keys of the same object, or `results` should be an array of objects.

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all you want is `true` or `false` and that as you wrote, it should "pass" (meaning `true`) when all steps have a `result: "pass"`, you could end up writing something like:

```
const checkResult = stepEntries => {
    return stepEntries.every(x => x.result === "pass")
}
const checkResults = (data) => {
    return Object.keys(data).map((key) => checkResult(data[key]))
}
```

and then call

```
console.log(checkResults(validationReportJson["results"]))
```

for this given data:

```
const validationReportJson = {
    "results":
    {
        "key1": [{ "step": "step1", "result": "pass" }, { "step": "step2", "result": "pending" }],
        "key2": [{ "step": "step3", "result": "pass", }, { "step": "step4", "result": "pending" }],
        "key3": [{ "step": "step3", "result": "pass", }, { "step": "step4", "result": "pass" }]
    }
}
```

will result in this output

```
[ false, false, true ]
```

meaning that the 3rd entry passed, but not the others

---

**Updated** from the comments

> For key1 passed in, I need the results combined. so that I can return "fail" is any fail present, else if any pending present, return pending else if all pass, return pass

```
const validationReportJson = {
    "results":
    {
        "key1": [{ "step": "step1", "result": "pass" }, { "step": "step2", "result": "pending" }],
        "key2": [{ "step": "step3", "result": "pass", }, { "step": "step4", "result": "pending" }],
        "key3": [{ "step": "step5", "result": "pass", }, { "step": "step6", "result": "pass" }],
        "key4": [{ "step": "step7", "result": "fail" }, { "step": "step8", "result": "pending" }],
    }
}

const checkResult = (key, data) => {
    const stepEntries = data[key]

    // if there's one "fail", should output "fail"
    if (stepEntries.some(x => x.result === "fail")) { return { key, result: "fail" } }
    // if there's no "fail", but at least one "pending", should output "pending"
    if (stepEntries.some(x => x.result === "pending")) { return { key, result: "pending" } }
    
    // if reached here, it can only have all as "pass"
    return { key, result: "pass" }
}
const checkResults = (data) => {
    return Object.keys(data).map((key) => checkResult(key, data))
}


console.log(checkResults(validationReportJson["results"]))
```

output will be

```
[
  { key: 'key1', result: 'pending' },
  { key: 'key2', result: 'pending' },
  { key: 'key3', result: 'pass' },
  { key: 'key4', result: 'fail' }
]
```

Comment: Thx.Close.I need to return "fail" if any result is fail else "pending" if any result is pending else return result is pass.

Comment: when you say "every" is that per key, or all keys? and you don't have any "fail", does that mean the result of a step can have the value "fail"?

Comment: Thx once again for ur elegant code. For key1 passed in, I need the results combined. so that I can return "fail" is any fail present, else if any pending present, return pending else if all pass, return pass.

Comment: updated answer with result per a given key

Answer (score 0):

With some slight modifications, a reducer and filter should do the trick. Any `result` that is not a `pass` will result in `passed` === `false`.

```js
const data = {
  "results": {
    "key1":[{"step":"step1","result":"pass"}, {"step":"step2","result":"pass"}],
    "key2":[{"step":"step3","result":"pass",},{"step":"step4","result":"pass"}]
  }
};

const { results } = data;
const steps = Object.keys(results).reduce((a, k) => [...a, ...results[k]], []);
const passing = steps.filter((o) => o.result === 'pass');
const passed = steps.length === passing.length;

if (passed) {
  console.log(`All keys passed`);
} else {
  console.log(`${steps.length - passing.length} of the keys did not pass`);
}
```